# Dual Boot issue with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16 on Asus GT 703G laptop

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

**Aim:**

I wanted to make it dual boot with Ubuntu 16 and Windows 10. Complete system specs are shown in the screenshot below.

[image: System specs]

**The things I tried:**

Based on various blogs particularly this.
The major steps I followed are shown below with screenshots:

1. Downloaded Ubuntu i386 iso from [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.4/)
2. Created bootable USB using [this](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/)
3. Made the partition of 300 GB in my D drive to install Ubuntu
4. Disabled "fast boot" option

[image: Fast Boot]

5. Disable Secure Boot option
6. Boot menu has 2 boot options. I have set higher priority to USB booting. As shown in the above screenshot.
7. Enabled USB Legacy Support
8. Save and Restart

Issue:

Once the system restarts, I am not getting the option to install or boot from USB. Check the below screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the mistake. Need to use amd64 Ubuntu iso file rather than i386 iso. It works for Intel machine(verified by [ask-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64)). You can follow the same steps as mentioned above.

Refer [this](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) for more details.